# django admin - matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

**Edit**
I think its something related to django-fsm, have a look at this code I wrote for States

```
class STATE:
    SUBMITTED = 'Submitted'
    VERIFIED_BY_DA = 'Verified by DA'
    APPROVED_BY_MS = 'Verified by MS'
    APPROVED_BY_DR = 'Approved by DR'
    APPROVED_BY_SrAO = 'Approved by SAO.'
    APPROVED_BY_R = 'Approved by R'
    AMOUNT_TRANSFERRED = 'Accepted'
    REJECT = 'Rejected'

    def __init__(self):
        pass


STATE_CHOICES = (
    (STATE.SUBMITTED, 'Submitted', 'Medical'),
    (STATE.VERIFIED_BY_DA, 'Verified by DA', 'Medical'),
    (STATE.APPROVED_BY_MS, 'Approved by MD', 'Medical'),
    (STATE.APPROVED_BY_DR, 'Approved by DR', 'Medical'),
    (STATE.APPROVED_BY_SrAO, 'Approved by SAO', 'Medical'),
    (STATE.APPROVED_BY_R, 'Approved by R', 'Medical'),
    (STATE.AMOUNT_TRANSFERRED, 'Amount transferred by AD', 'Medical'),
    (STATE.REJECT, 'Reject', 'Medical'),
)
```

So I have these two models defined in separate file under models folder in django
First I defined only Medical model and everything was working fine

```
from django_fsm import FSMField

from state import STATE
from state import STATE_CHOICES

class Medical(BaseModel):

    general_detail = models.ForeignKey(
        GeneralDetail,
        help_text='General Detail'
    )
    state = FSMField(
        blank=True,
        protected=not settings.DEBUG,
        default=STATE.SUBMITTED,
        state_choices=STATE_CHOICES,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.general_detail.employee.user.first_name) + ' ' \
               + str(self.general_detail.employee.user.last_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.general_detail.employee.user.first_name) + ' ' \
               + str(self.general_detail.employee.user.last_name)
```

But just after adding this below model it gives error in django-admin when saving a field in transition history using django-admin.

```
class TransitionHistory(BaseModel):

    state_from = FSMField(
        blank=True,
        protected=not settings.DEBUG,
        default=STATE.SUBMITTED,
        state_choices=STATE_CHOICES,
    )
    state_to = FSMField(
        blank=True,
        protected=not settings.DEBUG,
        default=STATE.SUBMITTED,
        state_choices=STATE_CHOICES,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.state_from) + str(self.state_to)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.state_from) + str(self.state_to)
```

**Error**
Exception Type: DoesNotExist

Exception Value:    Medical matching query does not exist

**Line 379**
 C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py in get
                self.model._meta.object_name

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? I have something similar

Comment: Well I don't remember solving this, but probably related to migrations only

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you have made migrations, if yes then there is a possibility that you might have forgotten registering your model in the admin.py

Comment: Yeah I have done everything, I think its related to django-fsm module